# Using iptables '-m limit' in the opposite direction

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I know I can use `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT` in order to limit the acceptance of `tcp syn` packets.
So if the `tcp syn`packets doesn't cross this rate, they will jump to `ACCEPT`.

Is there a way to write this rule in the opposite direction?
I want to write rules as following:

`If ok (doesn't cross the rate), continue down. Else drop` <-- `(1)` ???
`iptables -A INPUT -j OTHER_CHAIN_STUFF`

Is there a way to write `(1)` ?

I tried `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s -j DROP` but it works as:
Drop until you reach the rate, then, when you pass the rate limit don't just to `DROP` no more, so it continue down - this is not what I want.

Is there a way to write what I look for?
Something like: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn ! -m limit --limit 1/s -j DROP`
(pay attention to the `!`)

Comment: How do I flag this question for migration? maybe I don't have enough reputation here so I cant...

I tried looking in man page and on online exampales but couldn't find any solution for that, other than writing it differently with chains.

Nonetheless I think what I ask should exists

Comment: I can flag it for you. Which one would you like it ti be migrated to? I thought you only needed 15 rep to flag questions too. The flag option is located just under the tags.

Comment: Hmm `Unix & Linux` I guess?  
I have the `flag` button, but doesn't have a migration option inside..

Comment: I'd say Unix & Linux would be the best option. To migrate it, you can flag and choose "moderator intervention" or if you had 250 reputation you could "vote to close as off-topic...to miggrate to" your question. The only problem is, I don't see the option for Unix & Linux. I'll try something

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't make sense.  
It's the exact rule, just with a different behaviour.
Instead of `if it's below the max rate, and a tcp syn, ACCEPT` it would be: `if it's above the max rate, and a tcp syn, DROP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised a simple solution:

- `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP`
- Continue to do whatever I want

Answer (score 1):

A simple way might be to use the `hashlimit` module instead if you have it.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name mylimit --hashlimit-above 1/s -j DROP
```

It is slightly less efficient than the `limit` module according to `man iptables-extensions` on my Fedora 23.